# Can aframe-state-component track state across scenes?

Tags: aframe

I have an (angular 5 based) a-frame app that has two scenes.  I want to keep track of application state such as config parms using the [aframe-state-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-state-component) component.  I want to access the cumulative state across both scenes.  However, empirically it seems that every time I switch to the other scene all the variables in the state are reset to their initial state.

Also, the fact that you can access the state variables using a statement like:

```
AFRAME.scenes[0].systems.state.state.score
```

suggests to me that the state is tied to one scene only (scenes[0] being equal to the current scene).

At first I thought it was an angular issue as the supposed singleton service where I initialized state was being initialized on every scene transfer.  But I discovered that linking using the angular router:

```
this.router.navigate([(evt.target as any).previousSibling.getAttribute('link').href, {}])
```

Instead of the default:

```
window.location = this.data.href
```

Fixed that problem.  So it now appears to be an issue with A-frame.

Is the notion that this component can only be used *intra-scene* and not *inter-scene* a correct assumption?

Note: I'm also experimenting with [angular-redux/store](https://github.com/angular-redux/store) and it seems to have no problem retaining state across scenes, but I'd rather use *aframe-state-component* as it seems simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store in localStorage and restore on load. Something like:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
  localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.parse(state));
});

initialState: localStorage.getItem('state') 
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state'))
  : {
  // Initial state...
}
```

EDIT: Realized you meant for in-app scene changes? You can do something similar. When a scene is unloaded, store it somewhere, then state component checks if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

The state component doesn't seem to store the states, so It would work if you had two scenes on one page:

```
<a-scene></a-scene> 
<a-scene visible="false"></a-scene>
```

and switch them by setting the `visible` attribute. I also shows that `AFRAME.scenes` refer to scenes on the page, since you can log `AFRAME.scenes[0]` and `AFRAME.scenes[1]` in the above "example" (or in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/LfgskhuL/2/) fiddle).